# Android resource linking failed on android 3.2.1 SDK 28.0.3

Tags: java, android, android-studio

```
Android resource linking failed
Output:  C:\Users\aaaks\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\preference-v7-25.3.0.aar\503f5cce9a2dbf4cea415792d4546b49\res\layout\preference_widget_seekbar.xml:27: warn: generated id 'android:id/icon' for external package 'android'.
C:\Users\aaaks\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\preference-v7-25.3.0.aar\503f5cce9a2dbf4cea415792d4546b49\res\layout\preference_widget_seekbar.xml:53: warn: generated id 'android:id/summary' for external package 'android'.
C:\Users\aaaks\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\preference-v7-25.3.0.aar\503f5cce9a2dbf4cea415792d4546b49\res\layout\preference_widget_seekbar.xml:45: warn: generated id 'android:id/title' for external package 'android'.
E:\android app\IndiaKart\app\build\intermediates\incremental\mergeDebugResources\merged.dir\values\values.xml:3247: error: style attribute 'attr/colorError (aka com.td.indiakart:attr/colorError)' not found.
error: failed linking references.

Command: C:\Users\aaaks\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\aapt2-3.2.0-4818971-windows.jar\9f243ea060e047d10e80e3a1af0fa37f\aapt2-3.2.0-4818971-windows\aapt2.exe link -I\
        E:\Android\sdk\platforms\android-28\android.jar\
        --manifest\
        E:\android app\IndiaKart\app\build\intermediates\split-apk\debug\resources\AndroidManifest.xml\
        -o\
        E:\android app\IndiaKart\app\build\intermediates\processed_res\debug\processDebugResources\out\resources-debug.ap_\
        -R\
        @E:\android app\IndiaKart\app\build\intermediates\incremental\processDebugResources\resources-list-for-resources-debug.ap_.txt\
        --auto-add-overlay\
        --java\
        E:\android app\IndiaKart\app\build\generated\not_namespaced_r_class_sources\debug\processDebugResources\r\
        --custom-package\
        com.td.indiakart\
        -0\
        apk\
        --preferred-density\
        420dpi\
        --output-text-symbols\
        E:\android app\IndiaKart\app\build\intermediates\symbols\debug\R.txt\
        --no-version-vectors
Daemon:  AAPT2 aapt2-3.2.0-4818971-windows Daemon #0
```

Comment: Your attribute `colorError` is probably missing from your theme or it is incorrectly configured.

Comment: i am not getting the place where is the error is tried to clean and rebuild well its all happen after upgrading the android studio and yes there was an virus checkup run which found some virus int his files now i am not getting what to do...... help

Comment: is your package name com.td.indiakart ?

Comment: yes the package name is com.td.indiakart

Comment: have you created any attributes in attr.xml?

Comment: yes <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>    <declare-styleable name="CircularImageView">
        <attr name="border_width" format="dimension" />
        <attr name="border_color" format="color" />
        <attr name="border_overlay" format="boolean" />
    </declare-styleable>
</resources>

Comment: Taking a closer look into your log, there are 2 indication,First: something pointing to a layout file **preference_widget_seekbar.xml** and second an attribute named **colorError**.

Comment: preference_widget_seekbar.xml this file is from library which are not allowed to modify

Comment: Caused by: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.tools.aapt2.Aapt2Exception: AAPT2 error: check logs for details

this i am getting

Comment: then probably that library might be the cuplrit.. try removing the library.

Answer (score 0):

In your `res/values/attrs.xml` add:

```
    <attr name="colorError" type="color">#ff0000</attr>
```

Or add a dependency on appcompat to your `build.gradle` file.

Comment: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.tools.aapt2.Aapt2Exception: AAPT2 error: check logs for details 
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.tools.aapt2.Aapt2Exception: AAPT2 error: check logs for details 
com.android.tools.aapt2.Aapt2Exception: AAPT2 error: check logs for details 
org.gradle.tooling.BuildException: Failed to execute aapt 
com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: Failed to execute aapt 
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException:

Comment: You need to post the error from aapt, not the stacktrace.

Comment: I see now that you were referring to an attr not a color, see the edited answer.